# JavaScript Image Modal Not Opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, ejs

I am working on a class assignment and struggling with creating a JavaScript Image Modal.

I was able to get the images to appear clickable but they do not open up into a modal. I am very unclear as to which part of my code is incorrect.

I am using code straight from W3Schools Modal tutorial but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Below I have included all of my code (CSS, JS, and EJS) for viewing. I am curious if maybe the code is messing up because I am using both a Bootstrap Jumbotron and a Bootstrap grid system for these images to be formatted well and more eye-pleasing.

```js
        //get modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        //get the image and insert it into modal - use its "alt" text as caption
        var img = document.getElementsByClassName('portfolioImages');
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "block";
          modalImg.src = this.src;
          captionText.innerHTML = this.addEventListener;
        }
        //Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementById("close")[0];
        //When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display="none";
        }
```

```css
     /* Style image used to trigger modal */
    .portfolioImages {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .portfolioImages:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed; 
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 100px;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    }

    /*Modal Content (Image) */
    .modal-content {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px; 
    }

    /*Caption of Modal Image*/
    #caption {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 700px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ccc;
        padding: 10px 0;
        height: 150px;
    }

    /* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal*/
    .modal-content, #caption {
        animation-name: zoom;
        animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }

    @keyframes zoom {
        from {transform: scale(0)}
        to {transform: scale(1)}
    }

    /* The close button */
    .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px; 
        color: #f1f1f1;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .close:hover, .close:focus {
        color: #bbb;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="jumbotron" id="skills">
        <h1>Check Out My Design Work: <a href="https://www.slideshare.net/AmyWhite95"><img src='images/slideshow.jpg' height="100px"
                    width="100px" /></a></h1>
        <br />
        <!--Trigger Modal-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="Incontent">
                        <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/Cards1.JPG" alt="Card Design" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                        <h3>Card Design</h3>
                        <p>This was for a project in Typography I. The goal was to design and print a deck of cards
                            along with a box.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="Incontent">
                        <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/FrontPageNewsWhite.jpg" alt="Newspaper Design" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                        <h3>Newspaper Design</h3>
                        <p>This was a project for Media Design. The goal was to design the front page of a magazine
                            with good headlines and layout.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="Incontent">
                        <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/WhiteAInfographic.jpg" alt="Infographic Design" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                        <h3>Infographic</h3>
                        <p>This was a project for Media Design. The goal was to design a well titled and laid out
                            infographic.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="Incontent">
                        <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/vectorgirlJPG.jpg" alt="Vector Design" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                        <h3>Vector Design</h3>
                        <p>This was a project for Computer Graphics I. The goal was to vectorize a portrait with
                            Adobe
                            Illustrator.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="Outcontent">
                    <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/WhiteAWebsite.jpg" alt="Website Design" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                    <h3>Website Design</h3>
                    <p>This was for a project in Media Design. The goal was to re-design a bad website.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="Outcontent">
                    <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/SpecSheet1.JPG" alt="Spec Sheet Front" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                    <h3>Spec Sheet (Front)</h3>
                    <p>This was a project for Typography I. The goal was to design a spec sheet with provided
                        material.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="Outcontent">
                    <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/SpecSheet2.JPG" alt="Spec Sheet Design Back" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                    <h3>Spec Sheet (Back)</h3>
                    <p>This was a project for Typography I. The goal was to design a spec sheet with provided
                        material.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="Outcontent">
                    <img class="portfolioImages" src="images/TypeForm.JPG" alt="Type Form Design" style="width:100%" height="500px">
                    <h3>Type Form Design</h3>
                    <p>This was a project for Typography I. The goal was to create a design using only our
                        initials.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to create a modal for a menu popup on a restaurant site that worked.
Feel free to adapt it for your own uses. 
If you want to see it in action, go to https://codepen.io/lazav/pen/zLYpEV
I am not super advanced but I think I did ok creating modals that worked. Good luck.

```
//get modal1 element for menu
var modal = document.getElementById("menuModal");

//get modal button
var menuLink = document.getElementById("menubtn");

//get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("closeBtn")[0];

//listen for click event
menuLink.addEventListener("click", openModal); 
//listen for click event
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

//function to open Modal
  function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  }

//function to close modal
  function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  }
```